# Trying to filter before and after a date VBA

Tags: vba, date, autofilter

I'm trying to filter everything before 4/30/2013 on Column O and everything after 4/30/2013 on Column P. The problem is that once it filters for everything before 4/30/2013 the sheet gets empty except for the header.

```
Dim SalesDate As String
SalesDate = "04/30/2013"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$2258").AutoFilter Field:=15,Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:="<=" & SalesDate
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$2258").AutoFilter Field:=16,Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=">=" & SalesDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If those columns actually contain *date* values, filtering against a string value probably doesn't work, nor would be expected to work.

You need to declare `SalesDate` as type `Date` and assign it correctly.

`Dim SalesDate As Date` and `SalesDate = #04/30/2013#`

Answer (score 0):

as per my test you would have to convert the string date to a `Date` and then to a `Long` type

```
    Dim SalesDate As String
    SalesDate = "04/30/2013"

    With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$2258")
        .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="<=" & CLng(CDate(SalesDate))
        .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(CDate(SalesDate))
    End With
```